# Rotate 90 degrees in android

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, android-canvas

I am drawing on canvas using an array as the pixels:

```
 g.drawBitmap(imageBuffer, offset, stride, 0, 0, width, height, false, mPaint);
```

since imageBuffer is an array, not bitmap, how to I rotate while minimizing the extra effort to copy data in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `g` is the canvas, into which you're drawing, you can easily do this with:

```
g.save();
g.rotate(degrees);
g.drawBitmap(imageBuffer, offset, stride, 0, 0, width, height, false, mPaint);
g.restore();
```

And that should be it.